# How to define Test Data Sheet path in eclipse if the file is saved in project folder

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, testng

I am starting using git and jenkins for my test automation project, But i am not able to define the test data sheet path. when am using my local it was easy to read the file and define the path.

```
File src = new File("C:\\Users\\Automation\\CRMAutomation\\TestData_CRM.xls");
```

But now when i have kept the file in project and it in server i am not able to figure out which path to keep where jenkins server is able to read it.

Pls help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use path as below:-

```
./src\\Automation\\TestData_CRM.xls
```

It means your excel file should be present in the project folder itself. 
Create a folder in your project directory and paste this file inside that folder. This way git will also pushed that data to your repository and will going to locate by server as well.

answer of `karusai` is also applicable but in this conditon also file must present in project directory itself

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

if your project work-space is at C:\Users\Automation\CRMAutomation

```
String testDataFile  = System.getProperty("user.dir"+"\\TestData_CRM.xls");
File src = new File(testDataFile)
```

System.getProperty("user.dir") will give current work space folder path (i.e C:\Users\Automation\CRMAutomation ).

In Jenkins give custom work space as your project work space i.e  C:\Users\Automation\CRMAutomation 
should work.

hope this helps!